# Empty response when responding to XMLHttpRequest() from Flask

Tags: javascript, python, flask, xmlhttprequest

I have a flask app that processes a post request from a javascript file using the `XMLHttpRequest()` object on the client side. Note this app is running on the localhost.
I am trying to return a response based on whether server raised an exception or not. The server processes the request fine but I can not access the response.

Here is the flask route on the server side.

```
@app.route("/updatecontact", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def update_contact():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            sqltools.update(request.json['msg'])
            return "success"
        except Exception as e:
            return str(e), 400
```

And here is the function in javascript that sends the POST request and (is meant to) proccess the response back

```
function pushtodatabase(key, newvals) {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest()
    xhttp.open('POST', 'updatecontact', true);
    var msg = {"msg": newvals.join("|")};
    var msgjson = JSON.stringify(msg)
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
    xhttp.send(msgjson);
    console.log(xhttp.responseText);
    console.log(xhttp.status);
}
```

Yet the status is 0 and the responseText empty

I've tried with different response types in flask. I've tried adding these headers

```
            resp = Response("Foo bar baz")
            resp.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
            resp.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Methods"] = "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT"
            resp.status_code = 200
            return resp
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to listen to `load` event of `xhttp` object and add the event handler for it. See [Using XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)

E.g.

`main.py`:

```py
from flask import Flask, request, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/updatecontact', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def update_contact():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            return 'success'
        except Exception as e:
            return str(e), 400
    else:
        return render_template('updatecontact.html')
```

`updatecontact.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>update contact</title>
  </head>
  <body></body>
  <script>
    function pushtodatabase(key, newvals) {
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.open('POST', 'updatecontact', true);
      var msg = { msg: newvals.join('|') };
      var msgjson = JSON.stringify(msg);
      xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
      xhttp.send(msgjson);

      xhttp.addEventListener('load', reqListener);

      console.log('xhttp.responseText:', xhttp.responseText);
      console.log('xhttp.status:', xhttp.status);
    }

    function reqListener() {
      console.log('this.responseText:', this.responseText);
      console.log('this.status:', this.status);
    }

    window.onload = function () {
      pushtodatabase('key,', ['a', 'b']);
    };
  </script>
</html>
```

The output of the `console.log`:

```
xhttp.responseText:
xhttp.status: 0
this.responseText: success
this.status: 200
```

Comment: This worked. If I wanted to capture it as variable to use I would return it from the reqlistner function?